# Powershell assignment in expression?

Tags: powershell, assignment-operator

Does Powershell have an operator like Python's `:=`, which can assign a variable within an expression? (e.g., `if (match := pattern.search(data)) is not None`)
Suppose I want to store a value in Powershell as a variable, but also pass it down the pipeline. Is there a more elegant way than ...`| ForEach-Object { $foo = $_.split(': ')[1]; $foo } |`...?

Comment: PowerShell can assign nearly everything to a variable. So something like:`if ($variable = <expression>) {..`? is this what you were referring to?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala no. I'm trying to pipe an expression, but also store it as a variable for 2 steps down the pipe

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry, just didn't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to pipe an expression, but also store it as a variable for
> 2 steps down the pipe

In this case you might consider using the [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) `-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`). It has the advantage that the variable doesn't pollute the parent scope of the pipeline as explicitly assigning to a variable would do. It will just live as long as the pipeline runs.

```
...| ForEach-Object -PipelineVariable foo { $_.split(': ')[1] }
```

A **reproducible example** will make the difference clearer:

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object { ($a = $_) } | ForEach-Object { $_ * 2 } | ForEach-Object { "$a * 2 = $_" }
$a  # Print the value of $a
```

**Output:**

```text
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 2 = 6
3
```

Note that it ouputs the value of `$a` in the last line, because the variable has "leaked" from the pipeline into the parent scope. This may be an undesired side effect when you actually wanted to use `$a` only within the pipeline scope.

Now see what happens when we change to `-PipelineVariable`:

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object -PipelineVariable a { $_ } | ForEach-Object { $_ * 2 } | ForEach-Object { "$a * 2 = $_" }
$a  # Print the value of $a
```

**Output:**

```text
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 2 = 6
```

Now `$a` after the pipeline doesn't output anything, because the variable is defined only *within* the pipeline scope.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) to turn an *assignment* statement into an *expression* that passes the value being assigned *through*:

This allows you to simplify:

```sh
...| ForEach-Object { $foo = $_.split(': ')[1]; $foo }
```

to:

```sh
...| ForEach-Object { ($foo = $_.split(': ')[1]) }
```

The above technique works in all contexts; notably:

- conditionals:

  ```sh
  if ($files = Get-ChildItem *.txt) {
    "$($files.Count) text file(s) found."
  } else {
    "No text file(s) found."
  }
  ```
- inside a *single* expression:

  ```sh
  ($x = 2) * $x # -> 4
  ```

For use *across multiple script blocks* in the context of a  *single pipeline* (as your example suggests), the use of the common `-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`) parameter may offer a more elegant solution, as shown in [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71006648/45375).